# "Error occurred during initialization of VM" in linux server

Tags: java, linux, heapspace

I am trying to run java command in linux server it was running well but today when I tried to run java I got some error-

> Error occurred during initialization of VM
>
> Could not reserve enough space for object heap
>
> Could not create the Java virtual machine.

my memory space is -

```
root@vps [~]# free -m
         total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:     8192        226       7965          0          0          0
    -/+ buffers/cache:        226       7965
Swap:            0          0          0
```

How can I solve this problem.

Comment: What are the -Xmx and -Xms parameters that you start your JVM with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restart(reboot) system or server it will work well.

Comment: Are you serious? Rebooting is a temporal solution imo.

Comment: Glad you resolved this issue.  Please be sure to mark your answer as "accepted" when you are able.

Answer (score 0):

This error can occur when ulimits are set. What's the output of `ulimit -a`?